# Mysql - The Best Way to Manage and Find Point in Latitude Longitude Inside a Polygon

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial-query

What is the best way to manage latitude and longitude database in MySQL? I have very big database contain many location of restaurant, and I need to find what are restaurants inside the polygon (the polygon especially rectangle)?

For example I have database:

Row 1:
Latitude (-6.8374651)
Longitude (107.56283)

Row 2:
Latitude (-6.947151)
Longitude (108.261528)

Row 3:
Latitude (-9.125182)
Longitude (115.121831)

etc

I have rectangle with North West Point: (-6.4516,107.19281) and South East Point: (-6.81726,106.19271)

My question is how can I find the list of restaurants inside this rectangle in the most efficient way? I have arround 50 million rows of data and will always increase everyday

PS. I have created an index for latitude and longitude and try to query it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE latitude<=-6.4516 AND latitude>=-6.81726 AND longitude<=107.19281 AND longitude>=106.19271
```

But the MySQL keep searching it to entire table and makes the query become so slow

Thanks

Comment: If rectangle is fixed only store coordinates within it. If not please give more details of requirements.

Comment: No the coordinate is dynamic, user can define it flexibly where the rectangle and how big it is

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has [extensions for spatial data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html).

You can store points and other spatial objects all in a single column (a point in space is, after all, an atomic value, even though it appears to have an X and Y component), and then add an R-Tree index to the data -- B-Tree indexes (such as you find on numeric data type columns) are not well-suited for spatial querying because for every X in range, every possible Y must be evaluated, even those that are blatantly irrelevant, since the B-Tree has no sense of correlation across columns -- the two values are stored concatenated, which is great if you want every possible Y for a Given X, but inappropriate when the two values describe a point in space.

Spatial indexes are 2-dimensional, based on minimum bounding rectangles, so the "points" of interest are physically stored closer together in the index.

Until you have an opportunity to familiarize yourself with spatial data in MySQL -- which does require a bit of a learning curve -- you can optimize your existing structure somewhat by giving the optimizer two choices:

```
ALTER TABLE location
  ADD KEY longest (longitude,latitude),
  ADD KEY latlong (latitude,longitude);
```

This will sometimes allow the optimizer to discover that there is less work to do by searching lat then scanning long, or by searching long then scanning lat, and and in each case, it should perform better than individual indexes, if that is what you have now.

Also, as is the case with all queries, don't use `SELECT *`.  SELECT only the columns you really need, because this often gives the optimizer more choices for finding the data while doing less work.  Particularly, here, after adding the indexes I suggested, you may find that selecting only the (id, latitude, longitude) is faster than you expect compared to selecting all the columns.